# Use R and Openxlsx to output a list of dataframes as worksheets in a single Excel file

Tags: r, excel, lapply, xlsx, openxlsx

I have a set of CSV files. I want to package them up and export the data to a single Excel file that contains multiple worksheets. I read in the CSV files as a set of data frames.

My problem is how to construct the command in `openxlsx`, I can do it manually, but I am having a list construction issue. Specifically how to add a data frame as a subcomponent of a named list and then pass as a parameter to `write.xlsx()`

### Example

Ok, so I first list the CSV files on disk and generate a set of data frames in memory...

```
# Generate a list of csv files on disk and shorten names... 
filePath <- "../02benchmark/results/results_20170330/"
filePattern <- "*.csv"
fileListwithPath = list.files(path = filePath, pattern = filePattern, full.names = TRUE)
fileList = list.files(path = filePath, pattern = filePattern, full.names = FALSE)

datasets <- gsub("*.csv$", "", fileList)
datasets <- gsub("sample_", "S", datasets)
datasets

# Now generate the dataframes for each csv file...
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(fileListwithPath, make.names(datasets)),
         read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Example Output:

```
dput(datasets)
c("S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839", "S10000_T4.3.0_201703301843", 
"S20000_R3.3.2_201703301826", "S20000_T4.3.0_201703301832", "S280000_R3.3.2_201704020847", 
"S280000_T4.3.0_201704021100", "S290000_R3.3.2_201704020447", 
"S290000_T4.3.0_201704020702", "S30000_R3.3.2_201703301803", 
"S30000_T4.3.0_201703301817", "S310000_R3.3.2_201704012331", 
"S310000_T4.3.0_201704020242", "S320000_R3.3.2_201704011827", 
"S320000_T4.3.0_201704012128", "S330000_R3.3.2_201704011304", 
"S330000_T4.3.0_201704011546", "S340000_R3.3.2_201704010652", 
"S340000_T4.3.0_201704011010", "S350000_R3.3.2_201704010020", 
"S350000_T4.3.0_201704010404", "S360000_R3.3.2_201703311819", 
"S360000_T4.3.0_201703312134", "S370000_R3.3.2_201703310914", 
"S370000_T4.3.0_201703311301", "S380000_R3.3.2_201703310134", 
"S380000_T4.3.0_201703310509", "S390000_R3.3.2_201703301846", 
"S390000_T4.3.0_201703302252", "S40000_R3.3.2_201703301738", 
"S40000_T4.3.0_201703301752", "S50000_R3.3.2_201703301707", "S50000_T4.3.0_201703301724", 
"S60000_R3.3.2_201703301624", "S60000_T4.3.0_201703301647", "S70000_R3.3.2_201703301535", 
"S70000_T4.3.0_201703301602", "S80000_R3.3.2_201703301430", "S80000_T4.3.0_201703301508", 
"S90000_R3.3.2_201703301324", "S90000_T4.3.0_201703301400")
```

### Now we have a set of data frames and we wish to create a single excel file with multiple worksheets...

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
saveWorkbook(wb, 'output.xlsx')

lapply(names(myList), function(x) write.xlsx(myList[[x]], 'output.xlsx', sheetName=x, append=TRUE))
```

## Problem:

The problem is I can create the list structure manually and can confirm it works BUT I cannot seem to construct the list automatically.

```
myList <- sapply(datasets,function(x) NULL)
names(myList)
str(myList)
myList$S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839 <- eval(S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839)
```

thus:

```
> str(myList)
List of 40
 $ S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839 :'data.frame':    43 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ function.: Factor w/ 42 levels "DF add random number vector",..: 30 25 38 42 36 39 40 29 26 22 ...
  ..$ user     : num [1:43] 2.144 0.263 0.024 0.068 0.008 ...
  ..$ system   : num [1:43] 0.63 0.065 0.001 0.004 0 ...
  ..$ elapsed  : num [1:43] 12.274 1.104 0.047 0.115 0.009 ...
 $ S10000_T4.3.0_201703301843 : NULL
 $ S20000_R3.3.2_201703301826 : NULL
 ...
```

### Specific Problem: How to append each data frame to the list...

```
myList <- lapply( myList, function(x) eval(x) )
```

what am I doing wrong with lapply here? The above lapply() does not iterate through the list and append the data frame to the name list entry.

```
i.e. myList$S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839 <- eval(S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839)
> str(myList)
    List of 40
     $ S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839 :'data.frame':    43 obs. of  4 variables:
      ..$ function.: Factor w/ 42 levels "DF add random number vector",..: 30 25 38 42 36 39 40 29 26 22 ...
      ..$ user     : num [1:43] 2.144 0.263 0.024 0.068 0.008 ...
      ..$ system   : num [1:43] 0.63 0.065 0.001 0.004 0 ...
      ..$ elapsed  : num [1:43] 12.274 1.104 0.047 0.115 0.009 ...
     $ S10000_T4.3.0_201703301843 : NULL
     $ S20000_R3.3.2_201703301826 : NULL
     ...
```

What am I missing? All help gratefully appreciated. Yes, I am pretty certain I am missing something obvious... but... I am stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have your data frames, so I can't test this, but the code below is similar to the approach I use when I need to read and write Excel files. The code below uses the `xlsx` package, as that's what I'm familiar with, but hopefully you can adapt it if you need to use `openxlsx`.

```
library(xlsx)
```

First, read the files into a list. Something like this:

```
filePath <- "../02benchmark/results/results_20170330/"
filePattern <- "*.csv"
fileListwithPath = list.files(path = filePath, 
                              pattern = filePattern, 
                              full.names = TRUE)
fileList = list.files(path = filePath, pattern = filePattern, full.names = FALSE)
fileListwithPath = setNames( fileListwithPath, 
                             list.files(path = filePath, pattern = filePattern))
df.list = lapply(fileListwithPath, read.csv)

# Now we rename the List Names for use in worksheets...
# Remove .csv and sample_ prefix used in filenames...
# Reult in workbook S<size>_<R version>_<date>
names(df.list) <- gsub("\\.csv$","", names(df.list))
names(df.list) <- gsub("sample_","S", names(df.list))
```

You now have a list in which each element is a data frame and each element's name is the name of the file. Now, let's write each data frame to a different worksheet in the same Excel workbook and then save the file as an xlsx file:

```
wb = createWorkbook()

lapply( names(df.list), 
        function(df) {
          sheet = createSheet(wb, df)
          addDataFrame(df.list[[df]], sheet = sheet, row.names = FALSE)
          } )

saveWorkbook(wb, "My_workbook.xlsx")
```

I've separated reading and writing the csv files for illustration, but you can combine them into a single function that reads each individual csv file and writes it to a new sheet in a single Excel workbook.

Comment: Thank you. The code you supplied worked - much appreciated.  I need to spend a little time familiarising myself with list manipulation. If I fix my original code, I'll post an explanation. You have allowed me to move forward - your help is very much appreciated. Good karma and gratitude flying your way.

Comment: I am interested to see how I might change the name of the target worksheet from `df.list$sample_10000_R3.3.2_201703301839.csv` to `df.list$S10000_R3.3.2_201703301839` - simple I know but...

Comment: See update. I've added a line to remove the ".csv" at the end of each file name.

Comment: eipi10 - Thanks, I updated your example to reflect final code. I have to change the `df.list` names after reading in the files with the `lapply()`. Your help is very much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution with `openxlsx`:

```
## create data;
dataframes <- split(iris, iris$Species)

# create workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()
 
#Iterate the same way as PavoDive, slightly different (creating an anonymous function inside Map())
Map(function(data, nameofsheet){     

    addWorksheet(wb, nameofsheet)
    writeData(wb, nameofsheet, data)
 
}, dataframes, names(dataframes))
         
## Save workbook to excel file 
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "file.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

.. however, `openxlsx` is also able to use it's function `openxlsx::write.xlsx` for this, so you can just give the object with your list of dataframes and the filepath, and `openxlsx` is smart enough to create the list as sheets within the xlsx-file. The code I post here with `Map()` is if you want to format the sheets in a specific way.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be worth adding solution using [`imap`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/imap.html) function from the **[`purrr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/index.html)** package as it offers a convenient mechanism to access name *and* index of the list element in one call:

> `imap_xxx(x, ...)`, an indexed map, is short hand for `map2(x, names(x), ...)` if `x` has names, or `map2(x, seq_along(x), ...)` if it does not. This is useful if you need to compute on both the value and the position of an element.

## `imap` solution

*On dummy data for reproducibility.*

```
lst_data <- list(cars = mtcars, air = airmiles)
wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
purrr::imap(
    .x = lst_data,
    .f = function(df, object_name) {
        openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = object_name)
        openxlsx::writeData(wb = wb, sheet = object_name, x = df)
    }
)
t_file <- tempfile(pattern = "test_df_export", fileext = ".xlsx")
saveWorkbook(wb = wb, file = t_file)
```

Comment: you can use `iwalk` to avoid any message on console